# Camera models for intermediate and beginners

Tags: camera-basics

I'm starting to get into photography and wanting to take a class.
The camera that they are requesting needs to the following specifications

camera with the ability to independently set aperture and shutter speeds, or a digital camera of at least 4 megapixels with the same abilities as above

Use of a digital or film 35 mm SLR camera is required

I would like to purchase a film camera rather than a digital one.

Which camera would you suggest for a beginner but also use it at an intermediate level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With which film camera should I start?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/76985/with-which-film-camera-should-i-start)

Comment: What are your reasons to select film ? Have a look at [What kind of photography is still better done with film cameras?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/886/what-kind-of-photography-is-still-better-done-with-film-cameras)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm getting started in photography and taking a photography class — what camera should I buy?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5641/im-getting-started-in-photography-and-taking-a-photography-class-what-camera)

Answer (score 3):

We don't do shopping recommendations here (what we suggest is going to be useless next year when there are different cameras available), but I'd **strongly** advise buying digital rather than film.

The ability to instantly see your photo, and the effect that changing settings has, is *absolutely critical* for a beginner. With a film camera, the feedback loop from teaching a photo to bring able to see it and learn from it is hours or days; with a digital camera, it's *seconds*. Which do you think is going to let you learn quicker?